# Can not call image from url in style.php

Tags: php

If I try to show an image after including my functions.php file into my style.php file, it will not show.   When I delete the functions.php file, the image shows.

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
    include "inc/functions.php"; //when i delete this line, then the image will show up, but if i don't then the image won't show up.
?>
body {
    color: #000;
    background-image :url(http://127.0.0.1/niche/template/img/bg-image.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-size: cover;
    font-family: 'Squada One', cursive;
    }
```

Comment: You must have some bad code in your functions.php that is causing the page to stop loading. Check your error log.

Comment: Some formatting improvement.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just the actual CSS you are after then why are you calling functions within it? Have you tried the inspector tool to see if the CSS is actually showing and whether something within the function file is outputting some data which is making the CSS file invalid therefore not working correctly

Answer (score 0):

Surround your css with style tags

```
<style>
    body {
         color: #000;
         background-image :url(http://127.0.0.1/niche/template/img/bg-image.jpg);
         background-repeat: repeat-x;
         background-size: cover;
         font-family: 'Squada One', cursive;
    }
    </style>
```